# Merge two associative arrays by pushing their values into a new array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have the following two arrays:

```
$arrFoo = array(
    'a' => 12,
    'b' => 17,
);
$arrBar = array(
    'a' => 9,
    'c' => 4,
);
```

And i want the resulting array to look like this:

```
$arrResult = array(
    'a' => array ( 12, 9 ),
    'b' => array ( 17 ),
    'c' => array ( 4 ),
);
```

Is there a native PHP function to achieve this without using foreach?

Comment: Than downvote it better to edit the question, because the answers have different structure of array :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$arrFoo = array(
    'a' => 12,
    'b' => 17,
);
$arrBar = array(
    'a' => 9,
    'c' => 4,
);

$arrResult = array_merge_recursive($arrFoo, $arrBar);

var_dump($arr);

?>
```

With the array_merge_recursive you can merge the arrays in the way you're asking for.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: Your result is not what OP wants

Comment: @Djip Thank you very much! I never thought it would be that easy. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use [array_merge_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) method

```
$arrResult = array_merge_recursive($arrFoo, $arrBar);

print_r($arrResult);
```

Result will be:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 9
        )

    [b] => 17
    [c] => 4
)
```